# If is it possible save the same object to two different table Room?

Tags: java, android, android-room

Let's say I have obj

```
class Human{
List<Car> demagedCars = new ArrayList();
List<Car> newCars = new ArrayList();
}

@Entity(tableName = "carstable")
class Car{
@PrimaryKey(autogenerate = true)
public long id;

public String name;
}
```

So, room will create one table with name `carstable` I will save to this table objects from two lists `newCars` and `demagedCars`

How I can get it back to two lists?

I thought that it is possible to create two tables `demagedcarstable` and `newcarstable`

And save according to the list `demagedCars` to `demagedcarstable` and `newCars` to `newcarstable`

But as far as I understood there is no way with room to create to tables?

I don't wan't to change my object...

All that I need is create in one database 2 tables. And when I get list of `demagedCars` all that I need is to tell him `I want you to save to demagedcarstable` and when I get `newCars` list I tell him `I want you to save to newcarstable`. So as a result I have 1 database and 2 tables and it is up to me where I want to save this `Car` object. Question is: is it possible?

Feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

From a structural point of view, I believe you should store it all in the same table, let's say *carsTable* and add a status field to the car object. Then, you can query your *carsTable* and filter the results on the WHERE clause using that status field.

**EDIT:**

From a RoomDB point of view, your query would look something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM carsTable WHERE status = :status")
public Car[] findCarsByStatus(String status);
```

Comment: I am not sure that there is a good sample... All that I need is create in one database 2 tables. And when I get list of `demagedCars` all that I need is to tell him `I want you to save to demagedcarstable` and when I get `newCars` list I tell him `I want you to save to newcarstable`. So as a result I have 1 database and 2 tables and it is up to me where I want to save this `Car` object. Question is: is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can have as much room databases for the same object as much as you want

```
@Database(entities = Car.class, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class newCarsDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
private static final String LOG_TAG = newCarsDatabase.class.getSimpleName();
private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
private static newCarsDatabase sInstance;

public static newCarsDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "creating new database");
            String databaseName = "new_cars";
            sInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), newCarsDatabase.class, databaseName).build();
        }
    }
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Getting the database instance");
    return sInstance;
}

public abstract CarsDao favDao();
}
```

For the damaged ones

```
 @Database(entities = Car.class, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class demagedCarsDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
private static final String LOG_TAG = demagedCarsDatabase.class.getSimpleName();
private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
private static demagedCarsDatabase sInstance;

public static demagedCarsDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "creating new database");
            String databaseName = "damaged_cars";
            sInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), demagedCarsDatabase.class, databaseName).build();
        }
    }
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Getting the database instance");
    return sInstance;

}

public abstract CarsDao DamagedDao();
}
```

Also, you can simply just add data to each one you can use the same Dao to both of them or if you want you can make a Dao for each one but as much you have only one class I recommend that you make one Dao for  both of them

Comment: I am not sure that there is a good sample... All that I need is create in one database 2 tables. And when I get list of `demagedCars` all that I need is to tell him `I want you to save to demagedcarstable` and when I get `newCars` list I tell him `I want you to save to newcarstable`. So as a result I have 1 database and 2 tables and it is up to me where I want to save this `Car` object. Question is: is it possible?